# Clarification of Classes

Tags: python, class

I'm learning python myself, but I just don't understand Classes. I've watched multiple Youtube videos, but everyone just starts typing code without really explaining every part of it. Do you know any good documentation, or tutorials on it?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: Unfortunately, questions asking for outside resources are explicitly off-topic for stack overflow. But have you considered the [official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html)?

Comment: See [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(computer_programming)) on the subject.

Comment: Also see the wikipedia article on [Object-Oriented Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming), aka OOP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can finish this small but effective sololearn course of python 3

https://www.sololearn.com/Course/Python/?ref=app

Or you can follow this link to specifically know more about python class

[Learn more about python class](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-classes-and-objects/amp/&ved=2ahUKEwin386k5cvtAhWXYysKHS9PDRoQFjALegQIRhAB&usg=AOvVaw0rW9oQm9-TI0w7UqEDLEw6&ampcf=1)